# mod-rewrite passing directory name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a mod_rewrite statement that will allow me to redirect from one domain to another passing the directory name. For example I need to be able to write a redirect from:

```
http://xxx.com/u/7hb9n
```

to

```
http://xxx.co/7hb9n
```

I have tried various variation that either give me an internal server error or don't send through the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

this will redirect `http://xxx.com/u/7hb9n` to `http://xxx.co/7hb9n`

use these rules if the .htaccess is at the root level.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ http://www.domain.co/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

or if the .htaccess is in the `/u/` folder, use these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ http://www.domain.co/u/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi I assume that I replace www.domain.com with xxx.com and fr.domain.com with xxx.co? If so this just give the following message: Not Found

The requested URL /u/7hb9n was not found on this server.

Comment: Yes sorry I used my test domain as example. Where is the .htaccess file (the root of xxx.com?) do you have other rules?

Comment: I have an .htaccess file in the /u directory on xxx.com. This has no other rules in it. There is also an .htaccess file in the root though. Would that make a difference?

Comment: ok my rule checked at the root folder so: /u/folder. if /u/ is a specific folder and you need to rewrite from there it's different. I updated my answer

Comment: Don't know how to format in the comments but I added the following but that still gives a 404 error on xxx.com... RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxx.com [NC]     
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ http://xxx.co/$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: oh yeah, it's $1 not $2 ( I need my coffee now )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4776/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-williamsdb)